# SMS to mail gateway

Tags: windows, gateway, sms

I would like to set up a simple and inexpensive SMS to mail gateway. I have a Nokia cell phone which I can connect to a pc with a USB cable. I would like a software which monitors the phone and, when a SMS arrives, forwards it to a mail address.

Can anyone suggest something free or open source, in Windows, which can do this?

EDIT:
I would prefer a solution which doesn't require me to send e-mail directly from the phone, because this would require outgoing traffic from the phone, which would be billed by the phone company. However this could be an acceptable solution, since I don't think I will receive many SMS messages.

I work in my city's local government, and I have to set up a way for the citizens who don't have a PC, but have a cell phone, to open trouble-tickets. I would like to set up a number where they can send an SMS which is then converted to a mail for our support team. Since this is experimental, I would prefer a solution which doesn't require a paid service or a contract with a phone company.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a possibility, but you might be able to roll your own using the open source project Gammu [(see Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gammu_(software)).

It looks like Gammu can run as a service on Windows, it can store received SMSs in the file system, you just need to figure out how to trigger a script to send these as email, using BLAT for example.

I have used Gammu to send SMS (from HP SIM alerts) and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

[Wammu](http://wammu.eu/) is a GUI running [Gammu](http://www.gammu.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page).  The info page says it supports "**export messages to mail (IMAP4, maildir and mailbox storages are supported)**".  There is also [gnokii](http://www.gnokii.org/).  There is no GUI for the Windows binaries.

If you are trying to automate this, nray has the better idea.  It might not be as simple, but it will probably work.  Something like [FileWatcher](http://www.datamystic.com/filewatcher.html) would do the trick if you can get the SMS messages to a folder.

If you have money, [Ozeki Message Server 6 - SMS gateway](http://www.ozeki.hu/) might be what you are looking for.  They have a free trial download.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search of SMS to Email yielded a few things, most of which I do not believe have any requirement for your cell phone to be attached to a computer.  Is there a reason why you want the phone to be attached to a computer?

Would [this](http://www.wireless-labs.com/sms2email/) suit your needs?

It might be helpful to know more about what you are trying to accomplish when trying to suggest a solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. sms2email could be a good workaround for my problem. However, I am still interested in a solution which doesn't require outgoing traffic from the phone, if the serverfault community can provide one.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively cheap option would be to purchase a [USB/GSM Modem](http://www.google.com/search?q=usb+gsm+modem) that you can insert a SIM card into and then just write a program/service to read inbound SMS and send an email as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115361/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-incoming-sms-messages/647930#647930

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind. However, I have no way to write a program myslef, so I'd like to use something already written. Thank you!